# In the strategy pattern, what's the best way to deal with shared behaviour?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, strategy-pattern

I have implemented the strategy pattern - is there a smart way to deal with the duplication of function2() and function1() below?
The IBehaviour interface has other members that don't share functionality.

```
class Behaviour1: IBehaviour
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        Function1();
    }
    //other functions of IBehaviour
}

class Behaviour2 : IBehaviour
{

   public void DoSomething()
   { 
       Function2();
       Function1();
   }
   //other functions of IBehaviour
}

class Behaviour3 : IBehaviour
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        Function2();
    }
    //other functions of IBehaviour
}
```

I already have one class to deal with this behaviour.  Then I realised that different situations require different behaviours, so in this main class, I create a Behaviour object at run-time.  I am reluctant to create yet another class for Function1 and Function2, so I wondered if there is something that I am missing.

Comment: You seem to have e encapsulated everything correctly. I AM not sure i understood your problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of two easy options comes to mind:

1. Make `Behavior3` inherit from `Behavior2`. I would only recommend this approach if you can establish a clear "IS A" relationship or this design approach could really give you problems later if things change with how `Behavior2` works in relation to `Behavior3`.
2. Move `Function2()` into a helper class that `Behavior2` and `Behavior3` can use indepedently.

Answer (score 1):

If it's better reuse in compensation for a little more complexity that you want, separating `IBehavior` into `IBehavior1` and `IBehavior2` could be worthwhile. Then `Behavior1` would implement `IBehavior1`, and `Behavior3` would implement both, etc. This approach would go along the same line with single responsibilty and (maybe) interface segregation principles.